# responsive design - squashed background image

Tags: html, css, squash

I have an image as a background however it won't resize when viewing it on a smaller screen i.e an iphone. I've attached a photo of it when on a phone screen as well as the code.

If anyone's got any advice on how I can modify it to fit my screen without looking so crazy it be great. Thanks!

```
#bgsecond {
    position: absolute; 
    top: 0%; 
    left: 0%; 
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%;
    z-index: -100;
    opacity: 0.90;
  }

#bgsecond img {
    position: absolute; 
    top: 0; 
    left: 0; 
    right: 0; 
    bottom: 0; 
    margin: auto; 
    min-width: 200;
    min-height: 100%;
  }
```

Comment: 'background-size: cover;'

Answer (score 2):

As @Sean-Stopnik pointed out, `background-size: cover` will do the trick. `background-size: 100% 100%` will stretch the image to the dimensions of its container, whereas `background-size: cover` will show as much of the image as possible while filling the entire container (without stretching). It does crop the image, but you can use `background-position` to control where the image gets cropped.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your CSS code:

```
background-size: 100% 100%;
```